# In python,how can the complete expression regard as the parameter in the function?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm learning *SQLAlchemy* these days,I have a problem about the sql query using of *SQLAlchemy*'s `session.query(cls).filter`.
In *SQLAlchemy* the sql query can be used in this way:

```
rows = session.query(User).filter(User.name=='Tom').all()
```

`User.name=='Tom'` returns `True` or`False`, so how can the filter  get the complete compression `User.name=='Tom'`, instead of `True`or`False`

Comment: SQLAlchemy redefines the `==` operator for its classes so it returns an object, not a boolean.

Comment: Try `print(type(User.name == 'Tom'))` and you'll see.

Comment: @Barmar Is that a magic?how can the operator be redefined the class in Python?could you give me a example,please!

Comment: Python implements operators by calling methods. Classes can define their own method implementations. So `User.name == 'Tom'` is implemented as `User.name.__eq__('Tom')`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much.I just find the same answer as yours.Python is so interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Now I find the answer.In Python the operator is a function of the object.
For example,`==`is the function`__eq__(self,other)`,and`[]`is the function`__getitem__(self,item)__`,code here:

```
class A(object):
def __eq__(self, other):
    print("equal",other)
def __getitem__(self, item):
    print("getitem",item)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    A.__eq__(A, 'B')               #equal B
    A.__getitem__(A, 'B')          #getitem B
    a = A()
    a == 'b'                       #equal b
    a['b']                         #getitem b
```

Wow,Python is interesting!